# "ru_RU" (russian) setlocale not working on date and time

Tags: php, locale

I am trying to use Russian language with setlocale:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"ru_RUS.utf8");
echo strftime("%A, %B %d", time());
```

Output is : 
Thursday, August 29

Expected is :
четверг, Август 29

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The "locale" always depends on the server configuration. Do you have Russian added to your server?

Comment: Have you tried this: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');` ? I think case matters and you might need to capitalize both letters in the second "RU".

Comment: What platform? Windows locale names (for example) are completely different to *nix locale names: however, you want [strftime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) for locale-dates, not date()

Comment: If I use setlocale(LC_ALL, 'RUS');
echo iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', strftime("%A, %B %d", time()))."\n"; it works fine, but don't know the correct way.

Comment: I am using window 7. @MarkBaker

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it! if you are using Linux hosting then try:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
```

will works fine. In case you are using windows hosting then try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'russian');
```

Answer (score 4):

For the Russian locale and UTF-8 it is possible to use such code. Work in **Widows** and **Unix**.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$locale_time = setlocale (LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'Rus');

function strf_time($format, $timestamp, $locale)
{
    $date_str = strftime($format, $timestamp);
    if (strpos($locale, '1251') !== false)
    {
        return iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $date_str);
    }
    else
    {
        return $date_str;
    }
}

echo strf_time("%A, %B %d", time(), $locale_time);
```

Result:

```
вторник, Октябрь 13
```

Comment: Sounds like so dirty hack, but apparently it's the only way it works for me. Because PHP returns "false" for setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8'), sounds like it's non-existent locale....

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8'));
```

The function setlocale returns the result of the system call. I think it should be RU, not Ru.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.
I just added missing locale on my system.
For Ubuntu, if you need add russian locale type below:

```
sudo locale-gen ru_RU
sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

don't forget restart your php-fpm after it